# Install ansible off-line from binaries

Tags: linux, pip, ansible, yum, rhel

we have rhel linux machine without network access

and we want to install ansible on that machine

but we want to install the ansible from binaries ( not like pip/yum install ) , because we want to avoid any pip dependencies issues

is any approach that is relevant ?

example of the legacy way

```
Step 1: Update your Control Node
Any time you are installing new software, it is a good idea to ensure your existing operating system software is up to date. Let’s start with that task first.

yum update

Step 2: Install the EPEL Repository
Installing Ansible is pretty straightforward. First, we’ll need to install the CentOS 7 EPEL repository.

yum install epel-release

Step 3: Install Ansible
Next, we install the Ansible package from the EPEL repository.

yum install ansible
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "from binaries". Ansible is based on Python, and there's no such thing as binary Ansible AFAIK. You either install via yum, pip, or, you could set up a virtualenv with it then transfer over to the non-networked server.

Comment: or at least what is the better approach to installed it off-line by pip/yum

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline+installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the official [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-on-rhel-centos-or-fedora) you can use rpm available in official release repo. Since you dont have internet access you will have to download it somewhere else & copy it over to control node.

```
RPMs for currently supported versions of RHEL, CentOS, and Fedora are available from EPEL as well as releases.ansible.com.
```

Or

```
You can also build an RPM yourself. From the root of a checkout or tarball, use the make rpm command to build an RPM you can distribute and install
```

However I would not recommend [Running Ansible from source (devel)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#id24) because as already mentioned in the doc, this could be unstable.

```
Note

You should only run Ansible from devel if you are actively developing content for Ansible. This is a rapidly changing source of code and can become unstable at any point.
```

If you would like to build rpm on your own, you should probably use the [tagged releases](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#finding-tarballs-of-tagged-releases). 
Available both in [github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/releases) & [Ansible releases](https://releases.ansible.com/ansible/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not ideal, but you can just run from source.  I've done it that way for years without any problems.  I just put the initialization routine in my `.bashrc` file, so it's always ready to use.
[Running Ansible from source (devel)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#running-ansible-from-source-devel)

Once you pull from git on a machine that has internet access, sneakernet it over to the machine you want it on.